# how to create this css?

Tags: html, css

I have to follow divs:

```
   <div id="cont">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">example.com</div>
        <div class="col">text1</div>                   
        <div class="col"><b>text1</b></div>
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">example2.com</div>
        <div class="col">text2</div>                   
        <div class="col"><b>text2</b></div>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

I would like to understand how to write the css for this "table".

i think `class="col"` needs float:left (becase each div must to be consecutive, horizontally), but how to

write `class="row"` ?

**EDIT:** I don't want a table, I wrote "table" because I need the same think of:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but I need to do that only using divs.

Comment: If it's tabular data, use a table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your css should be:

```
.row{
    display:block;
}

.col{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;/*for example*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `table`

When people say you shouldn't use tables, they are referring to layout structure. It is still fine to use it in this case, they are not evil!

Comment: I need to use divs, please read the edit in the original message

Comment: @Dail - Why? Is this markup not going to be used to store tabular data?

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS as shown below. These make your DIVs look like a table **( http://jsfiddle.net/H7NQV/)**. Your example looks like tabular data, so I recommend using a table though.
 The `<table>` tag supports features which are not (yet) implemented in CSS, such as `colspan` and `rowspan`.

```
.cont {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I need to use divs, please read the edit in the original message

Comment: @Dail My answer is not altering your HTML code. I added the CSS to implement your idea using DIVs, while offering a tip to switch to tables. **DIVs-only table: http://jsfiddle.net/H7NQV/**

Answer (score 0):

How is your class `row`supposed to be rendered? I think it should look correct if you don't configure it at all. Anyways, you should use a table for tabular data.

Comment: I need to use divs, please read the edit in the original message

Comment: Why do you _need_ to use divs?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this post about [CSS tables vs. HTML tables](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/tables/). This should answer your question on how to do it. Also it will make you consider whether you get any real value from using css tables instead of just plain table in your case.