# creating the same thing with divs as tables

Tags: html, css

I started looking into CSS more deeply and decided I would like to convert my site's html that mainly consists of tables to divs.

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with divs as with tables on this test page. But I'm having a few problems:

1. Couldn't make columns
2. Vertical text alignment

How far I've gotten:
 [image: table vs div]

Code:

```
 <style type="text/css">


body {
background-color:#000;
}


 /* TABLE CSS */
 td {
    font-family: Tahoma; 
    font-size: 12px;

}
.line {
   border-collapse:separate;
   border:1px solid #222222;
   border-spacing:1px 1px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   background-color: #000000;
   padding: 1px;
   width:400px;

}
.topic {
    background-color:#3C0;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 23px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}
.row {
    background-color: #111111;

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color: #ffffff;
    height:12px;
    line-height:21px;
    padding:0px; 
}
.row:Hover {
    background-color: #252525;
}

/* DIV CSS */
div.line {
   border-collapse:separate;
   border:1px solid #222222;
   border-spacing:1px 1px;
   align:center;
   background-color: #000000;
   padding: 1px;
   width:400px;

}
div.topic {
    background-color:#3C0;
    font-family: Tahoma; 
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 23px;
    font-color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;

 }
div.row {
    background-color: #111111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding:6px; 
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size:12px;

}

div.row:Hover {
    background-color: #252525;
}

</style>
<body>


<table class="line">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="topic" colspan="3">Table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td width="20%" align="left">Test</td>
      <td width="20%" align="center">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td align="left">Test</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <p>
 <div class="line">
 <div class="topic">Div</div>
 <div class="row">Test</div><div class="row">1</div>
 <div class="row">Test</div><div class="row">2</div>
 </div>
</p>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There are possibilities where tables are better then divs (for example representation of tabular data).

Comment: @Truth well I heard that it's better if I only use tables or divs, not both. At the moment my layout uses tables for everything. I'm trying to convert the whole thing to divs and css.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yes, they should both use 50%

Comment: @domino Fixed means a fixed value in pixels. Does that layout have a fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <h2> Div </h2>
    <div class="section">
        <div> Test </div>
        <div> 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div> Test </div>
        <div> 2 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    border: 2px solid #333;
    padding: 2px;
}

h2 {
    background: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4px 0;
}

.section {
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.section > div {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 0;
}

.section > div + div {
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jNQrM/1/

Comment: Thanks, this explain a lot. section > div + div - never seen something like that in a css file. Can you tell me what that is so I can look it up?

Comment: @domino `X > Y` is the [child combinator selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators). `X + Y` is the [adjacent sibling combinator selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators). The selector `.section > div + div` matches all DIV elements which parent has the class `'section'` and which previous sibling is also a DIV element. Effectively, I'm selecting all DIV's inside `.section` which are not the first childs, ergo, the second DIV, the third DIV, ect. (In your case, each `.section` only contains two DIV, so only the second ones are matched.)

Answer (score 5):

It's good to see that you are converting `table`s into `div`s, however make sure you only do this where necessary.

If the data on the page is tabular, then it makes sense for this to be put in a `table` element.

`Div`'s are for layout and structure, `table`'s are for displaying tabular data.

A collegue of mine once spent ages building a forum out of divs which followed a table structure. This was all because he'd been told "tables are bad, use divs and CSS". It's important to remember this is only referring to layout structure.

If your structure has rows and columns, then use a table. tables are still valid useful HTML elements, and are far from deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that they shouldn't be mixed and only one should be used.

Comment: @domino - Nope, theres nothing wrong with using HTML tables for displaying data, and its definitely the better method than using divs. Its also better in terms of accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a good book - I recommend *CSS: The Missing Manual (Missing Manuals)*
2. look up `float` a long with `display` esp `relative`

Answer (score 0):

Put float:left; on this class :
    div.row

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the css display property.

```
.line {
display: table;
}

.row {
display: table-cell;
}
```

But you should get some problems with internet explorer. In that caase you could use display: inline; with a zoom:1;