# Colspan/Rowspan for elements whose display is set to table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.colspan2 {
  /* What to do here? */
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell colspan2">Cell</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pretty straightforward. How do I add a colspan (or the equivalent of colspan) for elements with `display: table-cell`?

Comment: Can't you just use a table? It would be a lot easier. Plus if this is tabular data it would be more semantic too.

Comment: @thirtydot it probably can, it would just be a pain and unnecessary. Grid systems like 960 basically achieve this but for an entire page layout.

Comment: @MrMisterMan: I'm not sure what you're saying. 960.gs doesn't use `display: table-cell`.

Comment: @thirtydot sorry, I forgot the specific question the OP had asked. You're right, you can't add a colspan through CSS. I was pointing out that you *can* make div's behave like rows and columns and that includes cells spanning multiple columns.

Comment: Use a simulated table as you do for your first level of organisation, wich will give you the ability to create a sticky footer for example. for your colspan emulation, you can created a nested table in your unique cell, wich will have a single row and as many cell you need, or use simple floating div.

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4746061/1429387) for div table colspan.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As far as I know, the lack of colspan/rowspan is just one of the limitations of `display:table`. See this post:

http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

Answer (score 30):

Since OP does not *explicitly* rule that solution must be pure CSS, I'll be stubborn and throw in my workaround I figured out today, especially since it's much more elegant than having a table inside a table.

Example equals to <table> with two cells per row and two rows, where the cell in the second row is a td with `colspan="2"`.

I have tested this with Iceweasel 20, Firefox 23 and IE 10.

```css
div.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div.row {
  display: table-row;
}

div.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div.colspan,
div.colspan+div.cell {
  border: 0;
}

div.colspan>div {
  width: 1px;
}

div.colspan>div>div {
  position: relative;
  width: 99px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">cell 1</div>
        <div class="cell">cell 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell colspan">
            <div><div>
                cell 3
            </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live action (demo) [here](http://atkkierratys.com/demot/csstablewithcolspan.htm).

EDIT:
I finetuned the code to be more printer-friendly, as they leave background-colors out by default. I also created [rowspan-demo](http://atkkierratys.com/demot/csstablewithrowspan.htm), inspired by late answer here.

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution. But instead, I have 5 cells on top row. On the bottom row, I need 1 cell same size as top row. Then one cell having colspan=2 and another cell having colspan=2 making it total of 5 cells in the bottom row as well. Here's the jsfiddle problem based on your solution. Any thoughts? https://jsfiddle.net/7wdza4ye/1/

Comment: @VarunVerma, you must add empty cell between cells 7 and 8. Just adding `<div class="cell"></div>` works (at least with Firefox). With this design, you need to pad with empty cell(s). For example, if you had it so that cell 7 was colspan=3 and cell 8 was normal, then you'd need two empty cells between cells 7 and 8. Unless you'd design something else (margins? single customized div?). Also, width of 100px and 5 cells makes things tricky, because words stretches css-cells, overflow-settings doesn't seem to make difference. You also need to recalculate `width` for `div.colspan>div>div`.

Comment: it worked. Thanks. In fact, I did add an empty cell after cell 8 because the bottom border wasn't showing up. Here's the latest: https://jsfiddle.net/7wdza4ye/3/. Was sure how to get the border between cell 7 and 8. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @VarunVerma, with Chrome the outer border was incomplete without empty cell after 8, so it is required indeed. Simple way to add the border between cells 7 and 8 could be this: `div.colspan{border-left:1px solid red}`. It needs to be placed somewhere below rule that sets div.colspan borderless, or it'll be overruled.

Comment: Thanks @F-3000. That was helpful. For the rest, here's the latest link based on F-3000's solution: https://jsfiddle.net/7wdza4ye/4/

Answer (score 17):

A simpler solution that works for me in Chrome 30 :

Colspan can be emulated by using `display: table` instead of `display: table-row` for the rows :

```
.table {
    display: block;
}
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.row.colspan2 {/* You'll have to add the 'colspan2' class to the row, and remove the unused <div class=cell> inside it */
    display: block;
}
```

The only pitfall is that the cells of stacked rows won't align vertically, as they're from different tables.

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking for a straight CSS way to simulate a colspan, you could use `display: table-caption`.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.colspan2 {
  /* What to do here? */
  display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell colspan2">Cell</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is amazing you rock!

Comment: Using display: table-caption will span all columns and place the row at the top of the table, just like a caption element in html table, so this doesn't really work. Only if you want to span all columns on the first or last row.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use a `table`.

table's are only frowned upon when being used for layout purposes.

This seems like tabular data (rows/columns of data). Therefore I would recommend using a `table`.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929191/creating-the-same-thing-with-divs-as-tables/7929323#7929323) for more information:

[creating the same thing with divs as tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929191/creating-the-same-thing-with-divs-as-tables/7929323#7929323)

Comment: The thing is, it's not for tabular data, so I don't want to use a table :)

Comment: I don't get why CSSing everything to behave exactly like a table is somehow preferable to just using a table. Admittedly `tr`/`td` spam isn't the prettiest html but is that the only reason? Everyone says tables weren't "meant" to be used for formatting, but html itself wasn't "meant" to do half of the things we consider acceptable by today's standards, including web applications.

Comment: Nearly a year later, but -- Slight, I share your irritation with people avoiding tables for no reason other than "tables are out of style". However I'm running into a few responsive designs where it's useful to have a table not be a table, so it can be rearranged at lower widths. Learning I don't have colspan for divs is kinda disappointing.

Comment: I formatted my search bar and menu icons using table/tr/td. I discovered why I shouldn't do that when I started testing with screen readers. Android's TalkBack reads out the table, number of rows, columns, etc. as though it's a data table. BUT, then saw I can keep the table/tr/td if I use role="presentation" Noticed Gmail does that with its search bar formatting.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to span columns in CSS I used for my own situation.

https://jsfiddle.net/mb8npttu/

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.colspan {
  max-width: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell colspan'>
      spanning
    </div>
    <div class='cell'></div>
    <div class='cell'></div>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>1</div>
    <div class='cell'>2</div>
    <div class='cell'>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to augment `.colspan` with `white-space: nowrap;` to get the result I wanted, but it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution to make the colspan the widht of the entire table. You can not use this technique to colspan a part of the table.

**Code:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.colspan {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.dummycell {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell dummycell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell colspan">Cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

We use position absolute on the colspan to make it the full width of the table. The table itself needs position relative. We make use of a dummycell to maintain the height of the rows, position absolute does not follow the flow of the document.

Of course you can also use flexbox and grid to tackle this problem these days.

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.tablewrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  position: relative
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell.empty
{
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
}
.cell.rowspanned {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.cell.colspan {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tablewrapper">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell rowspanned">
        Center
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Top right
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell empty"></div>
      <div class="cell colspan">
        Bottom right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/bderevyaga/vmed3unx/)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done just with pure CSS and centering the text across the "fake" colspan.

The trick is to set the rows to `position:relative`, then to place "empty divs" in the `row` where you want to make the `colspan` (they must have `height` in order to work), set the `cell` where the content is in as `display:grid`, and finally, applying `position:absolute` to the element inside the cell (and center it as you may center any other absolute element).

```css
 .table {
        display: table;
  }
  .row {
      display: table-row;
      position: relative;
  }
  .cell {
      display: table-cell;
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
      height: 26px;
      padding: 0 8px;
  } 
  .colspan2 {
      display: grid;
  }
  .colspan2 p {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell colspan2"><p>Cell</p></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the appropriate div classes and CSS attributes, you can mimic the desired effects of the colspan and rowspan.

Here's the CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
}

.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's the sample HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">X</div>
                    <div class="cell">Y</div>
                    <div class="cell">Z</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">2</div>
                    <div class="cell">4</div>
                    <div class="cell">6</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <div class="table">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="cell">A</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="cell">B</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        ROW SPAN
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From what I'm seeing in both the questions, and most responses, is people seem to forget that in any given div that's acting as a "table-cell" you can insert another div that's acting like an embedded table, and start the process over.

***It's not glamorous, but it does work for those looking for this type of formatting and they want to avoid the TABLEs. If its for DATA LAYOUT, TABLEs do still work in HTML5.

Hopefully, this will help someone.

Comment: Firstly, HTML5 has full support for `<table>` - it's just that people should **avoid** using it for _visual formatting_. Using it for displaying structured data is where it **should be used**, unless something else (like `<ul>`, as a mere example) fits better for the task. Secondly, dude, 4 tables. You bring interesting question onto table (rowspan), but your answer cries for using `<table>` instead. I gotta see how my solution works here...

Comment: I'd edit my earlier comment, but timelimit hits in. As with my answer about colspan, rowspan can be accomplished with MUCH less hassle than with your... original approach. [See it yourself](http://atkkierratys.com/demot/csstablewithrowspan.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I never said HTML5 didn't support tables. Many people are simply looking to avoid it. Sometimes, when writing a web-app (as opposed to just an advertisting-type page), you need more of a fixed layout for button and/or control placement.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of colspan content as "relative" and the row as "absolute" like this:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    position: relative;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.colspan2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this at present.

AFAIK this would be covered by [CSS Tables](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables/), a specification which appears to currently be at "work in progress" state.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, where you can find how to apply colspan using div
https://codepen.io/pkachhia/pen/JyWMxY

HTML:

```
<div class="div_format">
            <div class="divTable">
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_lable">Project Name</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_value">: Testing Project</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_lable">Project Type</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_value">: Web application</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_lable">Version</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_value">: 1.0.0</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_lable">Start Time</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_value">: 2016-07-10 11:00:21</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_lable">Document Version</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_value">: 2.0.0</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_lable">End Time</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_value">: 2017-07-10 11:00:23</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_lable">Document Revision</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_value">: 3</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_lable">Overall Result</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell cell_value txt_bold txt_success">: Passed</div>
                    </div>                          
                </div>
                <div class="divCaptionRow">
                    <div class="divCaptionlabel">Description</div>
                    <div class="divCaptionValue">: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
                font-family: arial
            }
            * {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box
            }
            .div_format {
                width: 100%;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative
            }           
            .divTable {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;            
            }
            .divTableRow {
                display: table-row
            }
            .divTableHeading {
                background-color: #EEE;
                display: table-header-group
            }
            .divTableCell,
            .divTableHead {
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 10px
            }
            .divTableHeading {
                background-color: #EEE;
                display: table-header-group;
                font-weight: bold
            }
            .divTableFoot {
                background-color: #EEE;
                display: table-footer-group;
                font-weight: bold
            }
            .divTableBody {
                display: table-row-group
            }
            .divCaptionRow{
                display: table-caption;
                caption-side: bottom;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .divCaptionlabel{
                caption-side: bottom;
                display: inline-block;
                background: #ccc;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 15.6%;
                margin-left: 10px;
                color: #727272;
            }
            .divCaptionValue{
                float: right;
                width: 83%;
                padding: 10px 1px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
                border-right: 10px solid #fff;
                color: #5f5f5f;
                text-align: left;
            }

            .cell_lable {
                background: #d0d0d0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
                border-left: 10px solid #ffffff;
                border-right: 10px solid #fff;
                width: 15%;
                color: #727272;
            }
            .cell_value {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
                width: 30%;
                border-right: 10px solid #fff;   
                color: #5f5f5f;
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use nested tables to nest column spans...

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Cell</div>
          <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use 2 tables where the column span covers the whole row...

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Cell</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question was, how to do it using CSS.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that sounds like a really bad idea.

Answer (score -2):

Even if this is an old question, I would like to share my solution to this problem.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell colspan">
            <div class="spanned-content">Cell</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .table {
        display: table;
    }
    .row {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .cell {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .colspan:after {
        /* What to do here? */
        content: "c";
        display: inline;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .spanned-content {
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sknoj80/).
It's not really a span, and the solution is a bit hacky, but it is usefull in some situations. Tested on Chrome 46, Firefox 31 and IE 11.

In my case, I had to present some non-tabular data in a tabular way, keeping the width of the columns and giving title to sub-sections of the data.

Comment: Of course, you can always rely on a grid solution like Bootstrap's. In this particular case, I really needed the auto-width that offers display: table.

Comment: Also, if you want to give the spanned content some background-color, you will have to fill your tr with the full amount of tds :(

Comment: I ended up making a table, and redefining my concept of "tabular data" ^^