# What is the analog of colspan when use display: table; in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

The task is pretty strange. I have to create html table **BUT** I'm not allowed to use traditional `<table>` tag. My table should look like this:[image]

It would be easy to do it like below:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="5"></td>
     </tr>
     ...
```

but, as I said, I'm not allowed to use traditional table tags (`table`, `tr`, `td`, `th`). Here is [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Fp9/) of what I have at the moment. How can I get the same result as with `<td colspan="5"></td>` **but** using only divs and CSS.

**EDITS:**
* Table cell's width in one row must not be fixed, it should be dynamic and it should be possible to make them (cells) different width (in one row).
* Table cell's width in **different rows** of the **same column** must be **equal**. Like in traditional table. Only "colspanned" cell's width must be different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colspan/Rowspan for elements whose display is set to table-cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277661/colspan-rowspan-for-elements-whose-display-is-set-to-table-cell)

Answer (score 4):

As stated in *CSS 2.1* specification in part ["17.5 Visual layout of table contents"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-layout)

> Cells may span several rows or columns. (Although CSS 2.1 does not define how the number of spanned rows or columns is determined ...

So the answer is easy! Don't think of CSS *tables* exactly the same as HTML *tables*. As there are some differences like what mentioned in ["17.2.1 Anonymous table objects"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes):

> ... the "missing" elements must be assumed in order for the table model to work. Any table element will automatically generate necessary anonymous table objects around itself, consisting of at least three nested objects corresponding to a 'table'/'inline-table' element, a 'table-row' element, and a 'table-cell' element. ...

So you can do it this way (each row as a table and dropped table-row for avoiding unnecessary div block) until they specify a way for defining number of spanned rows or columns:

**CSS**

```
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 16.67%;
}
.wideCell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">One</div>
    <div class="cell">Two</div>
    <div class="cell">Three</div>
    <div class="cell">Four</div>
    <div class="cell">Five</div>
    <div class="wideCell">Six</div>
</div>
<div>One Two Three Four Five Six</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">One</div>
    <div class="cell">Two</div>
    <div class="cell">Three</div>
    <div class="cell">Four</div>
    <div class="cell">Five</div>
    <div class="wideCell">Six</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you lose a key feature of tables which is synchronization of the widths of all cells in the same column.  this could be worked around by setting fixed widths on the cells, but that is not always desirable

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

CSS

```
.table{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table .row{
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .table .row .cell{
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
        border: solid 1px #CCC;
        height: 25px;
    }
    .table .clear_float{
        clear: both;
    }
    .table .row .cell.rowspan{
        width: 759px;
        border: solid 1px #CCC;
    }
```

html

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">One</div>
        <div class="cell">Two</div>
        <div class="cell">Three</div>
        <div class="cell">Four</div>
        <div class="cell">Five</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_float" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell rowspan">
            One Two Three Four Five
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_float" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">One</div>
        <div class="cell">Two</div>
        <div class="cell">Three</div>
        <div class="cell">Four</div>
        <div class="cell">Five</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_float" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell rowspan">
            One Two Three Four Five
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_float" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">One</div>
        <div class="cell">Two</div>
        <div class="cell">Three</div>
        <div class="cell">Four</div>
        <div class="cell">Five</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_float" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell rowspan">
            One Two Three Four Five
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CSS [`float`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) and [`width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) to get the table-like effect you're looking for. What I'm basically doing is I'm placing 5 `divs` all with a fixed width and class name, and floating them to the left. The `wideCell` has the same [`width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) the `.wrapper` which just holds them all together in a nice block.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="wideCell"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width:510px;
}
.cell {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    float:left;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
.wideCell {
    width:508px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    float:left;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Fp9/3/)

Comment: Thanks for help, but this is not quite what I'm locking for. See my edits.

Comment: change `width` to `min-width`

Comment: Heres a jsfiddle with updated code, you can have different widths http://jsfiddle.net/L7Fp9/6/

Comment: @chriz .. why would you use float or width ? check this http://jsfiddle.net/xVTkP/

Comment: @user2125700 because of the effect he needs.

Comment: @chriz i think the idea of wide cell depends on the content and as the content grows the cell should automatically expand and also if you check the fiddle i linked they do it with ease without setting any width or floats.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot there is nothing like colspan in display:table CSS.
You can try this: [CSS display:table](http://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/JCJzt/2/)

```
 <div style="display:table;">
     <div style="display:table-row;">
         <span style="display:table-cell;">Name</span>
         <span style="display:table-cell;"><input type="text"/></span>
     </div>
     <div style="display:table-row;">
         <span style="display:table-cell;">E-Mail</span>
         <span style="display:table-cell;"><input type="text"/></span>
     </div>
     <div style="display:table-row;">
         <span style="display:table-cell;">Password</span>
         <span style="display:table-cell;"><input type="text"/></span>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div style="display:table;">
     <div style="display:table-row; " >
         <span style="display:table-cell;">
             <button>Send Message</button>
         </span>
     </div>                            
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this ( where data-x has the appropriate display:xxxx set ):

```
<!-- TH -->
<div data-tr>
    <div data-th style="width:25%">TH</div>
    <div data-th style="width:50%">

         <div data-table style="width:100%">
             <div data-tr>
                 <div data-th style="width:25%">TH</div>
                 <div data-th style="width:25%">TH</div>
                 <div data-th style="width:25%">TH</div>
                 <div data-th style="width:25%">TH</div>
             </div>
         </div>

    </div>
    <div data-th style="width:25%">TH</div>
</div>


<!-- TD -->
<div data-tr>
    <div data-td style="width:25%">TD</div>
    <div data-th style="width:50%">

         <div data-table style="width:100%">
             <div data-tr>
                 <div data-td style="width:25%">TD</div>
                 <div data-td style="width:25%">TD</div>
                 <div data-td style="width:25%">TD</div>
                 <div data-td style="width:25%">TD</div>
             </div>
             <div data-tr>
                 ...
             </div>
         </div>

    </div>
    <div data-td style="width:25%">TD</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this fiddle out i hope that would suffice what you need
[html tables](http://jsfiddle.net/xVTkP/)

**CSS**

```
div.table {border: 1px solid black; display: table; }
div.tr {border: 1px solid black; display: table-row; }
div.td {border: 1px solid black; display: table-cell; }
```

**Html**

```
<div class="table">
<div class="tr">
<div class="td">Row 1, Cell 1</div>
<div class="td">Row 1, Cell 2</div>
<div class="td">Row 1, Cell 3</div>
</div>
<div class="tr">
<div class="td">Row 2, Cell 1</div>
<div class="td">Row 2, Cell 2</div>
<div class="td">Row 2, Cell 3</div>
</div>
```