# Create an HTML Numeric Keypad without <table> layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, numeric-keypad

I am trying to create an HTML 'numeric keypad', like those found on some keyboards. I am stumped on how to do the layout without using a table.

[image]

I am using Bootstrap (v3.1.1) so my first instinct was to attempt to use its `col-` classes to reproduce the 4 columns of keys found on a keypad. This was awkward though and I couldn't easily get the sizing of the buttons to be consistent between the different levels of nested `div` containers. I failed fast.

I knew I could use a `<table>` based layout to accomplish this easily with `colspan`s and `rowspan`s. But it didn't feel right using a table layout for this, because it is clearly not tabular data.

I tried to get the benefits of tables by using the CSS `display` property's `table*` values. This was cleaner than my first attempt and the classes I used were more meaningful than the Bootstrap ones I was attempting to use before. Unfortunately, I learned that [`display:table` does not support colspan/rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277743/346561). Here is [a JSFiddle of that attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/gweebz/bRu88/). I tried to fake a `rowspan` on the `tall-key`s by using `height: 144px;` but that just increased the height of the entire row.

I gave up and ultimately created the layout with a `<table>`. Here is [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gweebz/7J6Hg/).

Is there a way to create a numeric keypad without using an HTML `<table>`?

Note: The heights of keys can be static values (e.g. `70px`) but the widths cannot. The width of the entire `keypad` is a variable percentage of the container, because responsive.

Comment: Yes! but you have to do this all using css

Comment: Have tried combinating "row" and "col-" classes ? Try using a row with the 3 first columns and a row for the last one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using float behavior, you can create this with a bunch of inline-blocks. Each of the blocks are floated to the right (because the big vertical elements are on the right).

So the buttons on the numpad are placed in the HTML from the top right corner going left. E.g. the first block is the `-` button, followed by `*`, `/`, `Num-Lock`, `+`, and so on.

In order to make a double-sized vertical button, I attached the attribute `v2` (you could've used classes for this, but I felt like being different), and to make a double-sized horizontal button, I attached the attribute h2.

---

**For a responsive layout, scroll down to the edit.**

---

### CSS:

```
container {
    width: 442px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: red;
    float: right;
}

block[v2] {
    height: 210px;
}

block[h2] {
    width: 210px;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<container>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block v2=""></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block v2=""></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block h2=""></block>
</container>
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YzAA/1/)

---

### Edit:

If it has to be responsive, you can use calc and percentages to make the widths fit:

```
block
{
    width: calc(25% - 10px);
    margin: 5px;
}

block[h2]
{
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YzAA/4/)

Comment: This is very slick! I especially like the fact that my `<button>` elements don't need any container elements. But why use the `float:right` instead of `left`? Wouldn't `left` work as long as I ordered my elements properly?

Comment: I tried to edit your fiddle to see if I could use a `float:left` instead, because using `right` seemed a bit awkward. [Here is my modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gweebz/2YzAA/5/). I changed the order of the keys to flow left-to-right/top-to-bottom. I don't understand though why the tall red blocks are causing other blocks to act like there is a `clear` applied.

Comment: @JesseWebb Yeah that is why I used `float:right` because the big elements are on the right and they push the baseline down for all future elements. The only way I could think of to fix that would be to apply a custom class to each element that would need to use margins (negative and positive) to move them into the right place. [**The result works**](http://jsfiddle.net/2YzAA/7/), but the code isn't really nice.