# Arrange UI-Elements in HTML (with containers, layouts, etc.)

Tags: user-interface, layout, sapui5

I'm working on a SAPUI5 application with XML-Views.
Now I want to arrange my buttons for example. They should be arranged so they form a numberpad like on a keyboard.

I only know the layout managers from Java or the layouts of a SAP Web Dynpro where I also used transparent containers.

So how can I arrange my elements in HTML? How can I use layout managers and is there such a thing as a transparent container?

Thanks for any hints! :)

Answer (score 0):

Arranging HTML elements in SAPUI5 is how you would in normal HTML. SAP does emphasize that code in `index.html` is to be minimal, however, so do your best to keep your coding done inside of your views. Your elements are likely to be contained in `<div>`, `</div>` tags, which, like any other HTML tag, can be manipulated using CSS.

You'll need to create a CSS file and reference it in your `index.html` file like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />`.

Additionally, you should be aware of the native [SAPUI5 layout controls](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html) and use them when you can as opposed to writing up your own solution.

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23077759/975624) post useful as well.