# CSS display table cell width not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a tabular structure with CSS, having relative widths.

CSS:

```
.dtable { display: table; width:100%; }    
.drow { display: table-row; width:100%; }    
.dcell { display: table-cell; }
#control_panel { width:100%; }
#left_nav { width:14%;  padding: 1%; }    
#chart_container {  width:84%; padding:1%; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id='main_wrapper' class='dtable'>
    <div id='control_panel_wrapper' class='drow'>
        <div id='control_panel' class='dcell'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='bottom_wrapper' class='drow'>
        <div id='left_nav' class='dcell'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div id='chart_container' class='dcell'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code before closing body tag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($(window).width());
    console.log($("#bottom_wrapper").width());
    console.log($("#left_nav").width());
    console.log($("#chart_container").width());
});
</script>
```

Output:

```
1356
1340
1282.2
3.2
```

Why is `left_nav` not getting 14% width of its parent, bottom_wrapper?

Comment: in table structure **td**  width will be the maximum width of **td**  in column .
that's why your not getting the 14% width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to remember about using `display:table-cell` is that it causes your `div` to behave like a `td` element. In your case, `control_panel` is assigned a width of 100%, causing the cell directly underneath it i.e. `left_nav`, to be stretched.

If I am not mistaken, you are trying to do `colspan` on your `control_panel`, right? Unfortunately, that is [one of the limitation of `display:table`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277743/1144203).

A workaround is to separate out your `control_panel_wrapper` and your `bottom_wrapper` into separate `dtable`. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/uj608w40/) for live demo. (You can remove the `border:1px solid gray;` from `dcell` if you don't like the border.)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
.dtable { display: table; width:100%; }    
.drow { display: table; width:100%; }
```

to:

```
.dtable { width:100%; }    
.drow {display:table;width:100%;}
```

Set drow class display as table and run it. It's working well.