# How to make table by CSS?

Tags: html, css

I try to use CSS **display:table** instead HTML table tags.

My HTML:

```
<div class="c_result">

    <div class="rp-row">
        <ul class="rp-first">
            <li>London</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="rp-second">
            <li>Male</li>
            <li>Female</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="rp-result">
            <li>result1</li>
            <li>result2</li>
            <li>result3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="rp-row">
        <ul class="rp-first">
            <li>Paris</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="rp-second">
            <li>Male</li>
            <li>Female</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="rp-result">
            <li>result4</li>
            <li>result5</li>
            <li>result6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.c_result {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.c_result .rp-row {
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.c_result ul {
    display: table-row;
}
.c_result .rp-row li {
    display: table-row;
}
```

The result:
[image: This is the result]

But my desired result is :
[image]

The border styles didn't apply too and when I try to use border it doesn't appear in the result , How can I do that ?

Best regards.

Comment: no define of table-cell ?

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs The result is same when I use table-cell for li(s).

Comment: there is an issue with your html, result is last `<ul>` but desired result `Results` are first col so you have to sort that out and also  set `float:left` to `c_result ul` CSS selector, here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j26q0w5g/, you can take it from here

Comment: @Shehary float with display: table; ????

Comment: @Shehary The table direction is not problem.

Comment: I updated desired result image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this already looking better ??

**edit:** colspan & rowspan not possible in css or with  a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18475451/4431269)

```css
.c_result {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.rp-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="c_result">

  <div class="rp-row">
    <ul class="cell rp-first">
      <li>London</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="cell rp-second">
      <li>Male</li>
      <li>Female</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="cell rp-result">
      <li>result1</li>
      <li>result2</li>
      <li>result3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="rp-row">
    <ul class="rp-first">
      <li>Paris</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="cell rp-second">
      <li>Male</li>
      <li>Female</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="cell rp-result">
      <li>result4</li>
      <li>result5</li>
      <li>result6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Edit:**

```css
.c_result {
  width: 600px;
  /* total width */
}
.c_result * {
  display: block;
  /* remove list items and so..*/
  text-align: center;
  /*center text*/
  padding: 0;
  /* reset */
  margin: 0;
  /* reset */
}
li {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  /*border is calculated in element width, outline not.*/
}
.rp-row > * {
  float: right; /*floats bases to right*/
}
.rp-first {
  width: 12.5%;
  /* 1/8 width */
}
.rp-first li {
  line-height: 198px;
  /* base = floor ( 200 / 3 (max split) ) * 3 (max split) = 198 */
}
.rp-second {
  width: 25%;
  /* 2/8 width */
}
.rp-second li {
  line-height: 99px;
  /* base / 2 = 99; */
}
.rp-result {
  width: 62.5%;
  /* 6/8  width */
}
.rp-result li {
  line-height: 66px;
  /* base / 3 = 66; */
}
```

```html
<div class="c_result">

  <div class="rp-row">
    <ul class="rp-first">
      <li>London</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rp-second">
      <li>Male</li>
      <li>Female</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rp-result">
      <li>result1</li>
      <li>result2</li>
      <li>result3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="rp-row">
    <ul class="rp-first">
      <li>Paris</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rp-second">
      <li>Male</li>
      <li>Female</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rp-result">
      <li>result4</li>
      <li>result5</li>
      <li>result6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The result get better but there are some problem yet. the column and cell height is not 100% and **male** and **female** results is not separate.

Comment: i'll help you give me a minute ;-) @Mike

Comment: I guess my HTML should change for **Male** and **Female** result. :)

Comment: @Mike there is a lot to change.. but will not work with this HTML can you change the HTML ?

Comment: I think so, let me try.

Comment: Do you have any idea about cells height?

Comment: Yes still looking for it :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but male and female result section is separate.

Comment: @Mike i explained inside the snippet so you can change what you like :)