# Why block element children inside css tables dont take 100% width?

Tags: css, html, css-tables

If I add block elements inside a `display: table;` element, they dont expand to 100% width of table, but instead expand to 100% width of first column of table. If I manually add a greater non-percent "px" width value to this block element, it also causes the first column of the table to expand wider with it. Happens regardless of the position of this block element (top or bottom).

I have a fiddle to convey the point: https://jsfiddle.net/ugdre5s9/1/. Notice that the `.table-caption-div` element at top and `.full-width-row` element at bottom and middle of rows are not expanding beyond first column width. I tried wrapping these elements in `display: table-row;` but that didnt help either.

How do I then insert an element as child of `display: table;` node that will expand to full 100% width?

Comment: [**relevant link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277661/colspan-rowspan-for-elements-whose-display-is-set-to-table-cell)

Comment: table-layout:fixed might help you to size and overflow your single cells row . table-caption for caption would too ... https://jsfiddle.net/ugdre5s9/3/ but this looks like a typical table , so why bother with meaningless div + css

Answer (score 1):

The block is being placed in an anonymous table cell that spans a single column.

You can't specify how many rows or columns a cell box should span in CSS. This is one of the biggest limitations of the CSS table model. But in your fiddle you can make the problem go away completely by just using a table and replacing your `.table-caption-div` with an actual `caption` element, because what you have there **is a table**, and should be marked up as such instead of a bunch of semantically meaningless divs (well, other than the full-width rows, which should be completely separate elements altogether, not shoehorned into the table as though they were part of the tabular data).