# How can display table-row behave like colspan=3

Tags: css

I need two rows, the first one have 3 columns and the second I need to span all the width just like the  `td colspan=3` would do

Or display: table-cell; behave like colspan=3

I am using `display: table-row;  width: 100%;`

How can it be done ?

This is my CSS :

```
<style>
      .boxer {
         display: table;
         border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      .boxer .box-row {
         display: table-row;
      }
      .boxer .box-row-search {
         display: table-row;
         width: 100%;
      }
      .boxer .box {
         display: table-cell;
         text-align: left;
         vertical-align: top;
         border: 1px solid black;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: Better to post the HTML too.

Comment: This is the HTML:
` <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red">
    <div class="boxer">    
    <div class="box-row">    
        <div class="box">
            <div id="logo">
                     1           
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="box">
             2
        </div>        
        <div class="box">
             3
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div style="border:1px solid gray">
        <div > 4 </div>
    </div>  
  </div>    
  </div>    
</div>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `display: table;` [it **cannot** be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277661/colspan-rowspan-for-elements-whose-display-is-set-to-table-cell) (cause sadly there's no `colspan: 3;` or `rowspan` property in CSS, therefore stylesheet is unable to mimick a real `<table>` element)

**but hey, `flex` to the rescue!**

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
.cell{
  width: 25%;
  background:#eee;
}
.colspan2{
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">Cell1</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell3</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell4</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell5</div>
  <div class="cell colspan2">Cell6 Colspan2</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Roko it help me a lot. I am just looking for CSS responsive for now

Comment: **Cool!** @ÂngeloRigo you're welcome! It's totally responsive http://jsbin.com/heriyo/1/ so go for it.

Comment: Can i try 2 rows, the first row will have 3 collumns, the 3 collumn rowspan = 2 and the second row colspan=2