# How to style div elements to form a table

Tags: html, css, dom, coding-style, css-tables

I have some divs and I want to form a table style.

```html
<div style="display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      left column
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;background-color:yellow">
      one column on this row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need two columns on the first row , and one column on the second row, that is going to be full width, like we do `colspan="2"`. But, can we do something like with with style?

Answer (score 0):

it is the limitation of display:table
you can not achieve desired layout with this, you can use flux do get the job done.
you can check it out from the link below

[How can display table-row behave like colspan=3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415226/how-can-display-table-row-behave-like-colspan-3)