# Adjust 3 box in a row using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-calc

I want to place 3 Box in a row, another 3 in second row. This is working fine if I do not add `margin: 2px;` and `width: calc(33%-4px);`. But if I add `margin: 2px;` and adjust in width as `width: calc(33% - 4px);` then all are coming in same row. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here with width `calc` method.

Incorrect Code -

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.box { 
  flex-grow: 1; 
  width: calc(33%-4px); 
  height: 100px; 
  background: green;
  margin: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box">Box 6</div>
</div>
```

Working Code -

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.box { 
  flex-grow: 1; 
  width: 33%; 
  height: 100px; 
  background: green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box">Box 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36415226/383904 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can display table-row behave like colspan=3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415226/how-can-display-table-row-behave-like-colspan-3)

Comment: another idea without the need of calc() and using flex-basis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020778/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin` should match the `calc(100% - <this value here>px)`
Also notice that **spaces** are needed in order for `calc(<value>(space)<operator>(space)<value>)` to work!

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.box { 
  flex-grow: 1; 
  width: calc(33% - 2px); 
  margin: 2px;
  height: 100px; 
  background: green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box">Box 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin apply to both sides so we need 2*margin inside the calc

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Exactly that is my question, why 2px is working but not 4px as I am reducing margin-left: 2 and margin-right: 2px from width

Comment: @Nesh the only issue of your code is the spaces inside calc() [like explained in the duplicate]

Comment: @TemaniAfif ohhhhh man ......thx a lot ..really-2 helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
width: calc(30%-4px)
```

to

```
width: calc(30% - 4px);
```